# Mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite Cannot update League of Legends Fix

Tags: league-of-legends, macos

I was having a problem where I could not update my League of Legends (from a fresh install) in Yosemite. It would get to 87% and just hang at 0 Kbps. Does anyone have the answer to this question?

Comment: This is a perfect question + answer, but you should separate them. You can answer your own question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the hardest time finding a fix for this, so I thought I would give those instructions here:

1. When LoLPatcher shows up in your dock, right-click it and select "Show in Finder". This opens a Finder window with 2 .app files: LoLPatcher.app and LoLPatcherHelper.app.
2. Right-Click "LoLPatcher.app" and select "Get Info".
3. Check the box that says "Prevent AppNap".
4. Do the same for LoLPatcherHelper.app.

Rerun "LeagueOfLegends.app" and it should scan the files for differences and fix your hang-up issue! Hope this helps anyone else out there having this problem!